# PPP hangs up after authentication

Tags: ppp, gsm

I am working on an Ubuntu 12.04 machine and could use some assistance to establish a ppp connection with my ISP via a Telit HE910 mPCIe module.

**ppp config:**

```
# pppd launch configuration used by pon(1) and poff(1).
# See the manual page pppd(8) for information on all the options.

# There should be a matching entry with the password in /etc/ppp/pap-secrets
# and/or /etc/ppp/chap-secrets.
#user "myusername@realm"
connect "/usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/telit-usbmodem"

# Serial device to which the modem is connected.
/dev/ttyACM0

# Speed of the serial line.
115200

# Assumes that your IP address is allocated dynamically by the ISP.
noipdefault
# Try to get the name server addresses from the ISP.
usepeerdns
# Use this connection as the default route.
defaultroute

# Makes pppd "dial again" when the connection is lost.
persist
holdoff 30
maxfail 0

# Do not ask the remote to authenticate.
noauth

debug
```

**chatscript:**

```
# You can use this script unmodified to connect to cellular networks.
# The APN is specified in the peers file as the argument of the -T command
# line option of chat(8).

# For details about the AT commands involved please consult the relevant
# standard: 3GPP TS 27.007 - AT command set for User Equipment (UE).
# (http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm)

TIMEOUT 60
ABORT BUSY
ABORT VOICE
ABORT "NO CARRIER"
ABORT "NO DIALTONE"
ABORT "NO DIAL TONE"
ABORT "NO ANSWER"
ABORT "DELAYED"
ABORT "ERROR"

""  ATZ
OK  AT+CMEE=1
OK  AT+CGMI
OK  AT+CGMM
OK  AT+GMR
OK  AT+GCAP
OK  AT+CGSN
OK  AT+CIMI
OK  AT+CCID
OK  AT+CSQ
OK  AT+COPS?
OK  AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","**HIDDEN**"
OK  ATD*99#
CONNECT ""
```

**log:**

```
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: timeout set to 60 seconds
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: abort on (BUSY)
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: abort on (VOICE)
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: abort on (NO CARRIER)
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: abort on (NO DIALTONE)
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: abort on (NO DIAL TONE)
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: abort on (NO ANSWER)
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: abort on (DELAYED)
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: abort on (ERROR)
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: send (ATZ^M)
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: expect (OK)
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: ATZ^M^M
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: OK
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]:  -- got it
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: send (AT+CMEE=1^M)
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: expect (OK)
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: ^M
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: AT+CMEE=1^M^M
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: OK
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]:  -- got it
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: send (AT+CGMI^M)
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: expect (OK)
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: ^M
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: AT+CGMI^M^M
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: Telit^M
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: ^M
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: OK
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]:  -- got it
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: send (AT+CGMM^M)
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: expect (OK)
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: ^M
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: AT+CGMM^M^M
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: HE910^M
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: ^M
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: OK
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]:  -- got it
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: send (AT+GMR^M)
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: expect (OK)
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: ^M
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: AT+GMR^M^M
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: 12.00.004^M
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: ^M
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: OK
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]:  -- got it
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: send (AT+GCAP^M)
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: expect (OK)
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: ^M
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: AT+GCAP^M^M
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: +GCAP: +CGSM,+DS,+FCLASS,+MS,+ES^M
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: ^M
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: OK
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]:  -- got it
Jul  1 18:05:01 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: send (AT+CGSN^M)
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: expect (OK)
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: ^M
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: AT+CGSN^M^M
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: 357164042205099^M
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: ^M
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: OK
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]:  -- got it
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: send (AT+CIMI^M)
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: expect (OK)
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: ^M
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: AT+CIMI^M^M
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: 310170230000285^M
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: ^M
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: OK
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]:  -- got it
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: send (AT+CCID^M)
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: expect (OK)
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: ^M
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: AT+CCID^M^M
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: +CCID: 89011704252300002851^M
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: ^M
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: OK
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]:  -- got it
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: send (AT+CSQ^M)
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: expect (OK)
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: ^M
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: AT+CSQ^M^M
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: +CSQ: 27,0^M
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: ^M
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: OK
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]:  -- got it
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: send (AT+COPS?^M)
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: expect (OK)
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: ^M
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: AT+COPS?^M^M
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: +COPS: 0^M
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: ^M
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: OK
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]:  -- got it
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: send (AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","HIDDEN"^M)
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: expect (OK)
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: ^M
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","HIDDEN"^M^M
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: OK
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]:  -- got it
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: send (ATD*99#^M)
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: expect (CONNECT)
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: ^M
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: ATD*99#^M^M
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: CONNECT
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]:  -- got it
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host chat[1277]: send (^M)
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host pppd[783]: Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/telit-usbmodem finished (pid 1276), status = 0x0
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host pppd[783]: Serial connection established.
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host pppd[783]: using channel 1
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host pppd[783]: Using interface ppp0
Jul  1 18:05:02 ubuntu-host pppd[783]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyACM0
Jul  1 18:05:03 ubuntu-host pppd[783]: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0xbd665e21> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Jul  1 18:05:03 ubuntu-host pppd[783]: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x3ca6e1fa> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Jul  1 18:05:03 ubuntu-host pppd[783]: sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0xbd665e21> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Jul  1 18:05:03 ubuntu-host pppd[783]: rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x3ca6e1fa> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Jul  1 18:05:03 ubuntu-host pppd[783]: sent [PAP AuthReq id=0x1 user="ubuntu-host" password=<hidden>]
Jul  1 18:05:03 ubuntu-host pppd[783]: rcvd [PAP AuthAck id=0x1 ""]
Jul  1 18:05:03 ubuntu-host pppd[783]: PAP authentication succeeded
Jul  1 18:05:03 ubuntu-host kernel: [   47.223101] PPP BSD Compression module registered
Jul  1 18:05:03 ubuntu-host pppd[783]: sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <deflate 15> <deflate(old#) 15> <bsd v1 15>]
Jul  1 18:05:03 ubuntu-host pppd[783]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Jul  1 18:05:03 ubuntu-host kernel: [   47.228283] PPP Deflate Compression module registered
Jul  1 18:05:03 ubuntu-host pppd[783]: rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x2 80 fd 01 01 00 0f 1a 04 78 00 18 04 78 00 15]
Jul  1 18:05:03 ubuntu-host pppd[783]: Protocol-Reject for 'Compression Control Protocol' (0x80fd) received
Jul  1 18:05:03 ubuntu-host pppd[783]: rcvd [LCP TermReq id=0x3 "User request"]
Jul  1 18:05:03 ubuntu-host pppd[783]: LCP terminated by peer (User request)
Jul  1 18:05:03 ubuntu-host pppd[783]: sent [LCP TermAck id=0x3]
Jul  1 18:05:05 ubuntu-host pppd[783]: Modem hangup
Jul  1 18:05:05 ubuntu-host pppd[783]: Connection terminated.
```

The odd thing is... last week, this worked just fine. Zero modem hangups... Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ended up being a provisioning issue with my MVNO and has been resolved. The above pppd and chatscript configurations work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% familiar with PPP, so I'm not sure of the fix, but your key line is:

`Jul  1 18:05:03 ubuntu-host pppd[783]: Protocol-Reject for 'Compression Control Protocol' (0x80fd) received`

It appears the ISP is rejecting the compression request. Perhaps if you disable compression it will work.

Comment: That was my first thought and I've tried this already. Didn't have any effect. I'm currently working with Telit to try and resolve this issue.